# how to search within shortcuts of tmux

Tags: tmux

Pressing `?` within a tmux session lists out the available shortcuts.

But there are so many... how can one search for some text within those displayed shortcuts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. My tmux's default mode was in *emacs*. I just had to switch to *Vi* (which I am comfortable with). So all I had to do was:
`set-window-option -g mode-keys vi`